# Gulp browserSync dont work with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, gulp

Im trying to use gulp browserSync with laravel and it doesnt work. im run it from the public folder like this:

```
gulp.task( 'browser-sync', function() {
  browserSync( {
    server: {
      baseDir: "./"
    }
  } );
} );
```

and its open the browser in localhost:3000 with the message:
Cannot GET /

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `proxy` option. So for example, if you normally access your laravel site via something like "homestead.app:8000", you would use config like this.

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
  browserSync({
    proxy: "homestead.app:8000"
  });
});
```

Comment: Or make sure you have an nginx/apache2 server set up and use that as the proxy.